# Iterating through an instance's attributes and stroting its values in a list, and using .join(), weird output

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, instance, getattr

this is an example code from a book:

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def describe(self):
        long = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long.title()


mycar = Car('audi', 'a4', 2016)

print(mycar.describe())
```

i was thinking if i could make `describe()` do the same thing, but be more dynamic. and made a change:

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def describe(self):
        l = str(''.join(str([getattr(self, a) for a in dir(self) if not a.startswith('__')])))
        print(l)

mycar = Car('audi', 'a4', 2016)
mycar.describe()
```

I thought the code for `describe()` made perfect sense but the output is a little unexpected..

above code output:

```
─$ python3 carclassup.py
[<bound method Car.describe of <__main__.Car object at 0x7f0f5abaa8e0>>, 'audi', '14', 2016]
```

1. Why is the output showing in a list? I tried to `str()` but it still outputs in list.
2. What is `<bound method Car.describe of <__main__.Car object at 0x7f0f5abaa8e0>>`? I would like it not to be output.

Comment: "Why is the output showing in a list? " Because you applied `str` to the entire list, not to its elements; and then tried to `join` the single string, which then iterates over individual characters. "What is "..."" It is exactly what it says it is: the `.describe` method on the instance, which is *also an attribute*. I linked duplicate questions aimed at addressing both parts of the problem. Please note that in general you are expected to ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it **is** one question. One question with two points